# Why is trace of energy-momentum tensor not a good candidate for the source of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, reissner-nordstrom-metric

The reason why I think trace of energy-momentum tensor can't be the source is that, in a static weak field $p$<<$\rho$

$$T^{\mu}_{\mu} \approx T^{0}_{0} = -\rho$$

and if in one system I have only $T^0_0$ component, this won't be true for all systems. Therefore, trace of energy-momentum tensor is not a good candidate.

According to what it was written in the following paper, it has something to do with coupling of gravity to electromagnetic field but I don't see how

[http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~cosmo/SW_2013/PPT/Novello.pdf](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/%7Ecosmo/SW_2013/PPT/Novello.pdf)

"The source of scalar gravity is the trace of the energy-momentum tensor: this originates the main handicap of all previous scalar gravity: gravity does not couple to the electromagnetic field."

Answer (score 1):

Such a theory disagrees with experiment. There would be no gravitational waves and coupling to a free electromagnetic wave would be impossible, as the trace of its EM tensor is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you elaborate what you meant by "coupling to free electromagnetic wave would be impossible" ? Trace of EM tensor is zero but how is it related to energy-momentum tensor in GR?